# Where $X$ is a normed space, show $U_1=\{x \in X:||x|| <1 \}$ is an open set in $X$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a normed space, show $$U_1=\{x \in X\mid \|x\| <1 \}$$ is an open set in $X$.

This is the proof:

Let $x \in U_1$, then $\|x\|<1$. Let $e=1-\|x\|$ so $e >0$.

If $y \in X$ with $\|y-x\| <e$ then by the triangle inequality$\|y\| \leq \|y-x\| +\|x\| <e+\|x\|=1$ so then $y \in U_1$ hence $U_1$ is open.

The definition of an open set I have in my notes is a set is open if it contains open balls around each point.

The other definition I have is a set is open if its complement is closed.

> So I don't understand how this proof shows that $U_1$ is an open set.

Comment: This proof shows that for each $x\in U_1$ there is $e>0$ such that $B\left(x,e\right)\subseteq U_1$, and this is precisely the definition of an open set.

Comment: Alternatively you have that for every $x \in U_1$, the set $U_1$ is itself an open ball containing $x$. Thus $U_1$ is open.

Comment: Looks like to me they just reused $U_1$ as your open ball.

Comment: @guy so in my proof, is y the open ball?

Comment: $y$ is a point, *not* an open ball.